# Get SQL result ordered by a column value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the results ordered by a column value. I have this basic query:

```
SELECT `product_id`,
       (SELECT `name`
        FROM   `specifications` s
        WHERE  `specification_id` = sp.`specification_id`) AS Specification,
       `value`
FROM   `specs-product` sp
WHERE  `product_id` = '4'
       AND ( `specification_id` = '88'
              OR `specification_id` = '103'
              OR `specification_id` = '18'
              OR `specification_id` = '15'
              OR `specification_id` = '157'
              OR `specification_id` = '89'
              OR `specification_id` = '9'
              OR `specification_id` = '223'
              OR `specification_id` = '224'
              OR `specification_id` = '29'
              OR `specification_id` = '87'
              OR `specification_id` = '219'
              OR `specification_id` = '218'
              OR `specification_id` = '220' )
```

I've a column name in the table `specifications` called `priority`. I need to get the result ordered by this priority values.

I've tried to add `order by s.'priority'` But didn't work. How can I do this?

Table Structure as Follows:

`specifications`

```
+------------------+------+----------+
| specification_id | name | priority |
+------------------+------+----------+
| 1                | abc  |        5 |
| 2                | xxxx |        2 |
| 3 ababab         | 3    |          |
+------------------+------+----------+
```

`PRODUCTS` TABLE

```
+------------+------------+--+
| product_id | reference  |  |
+------------+------------+--+
|          1 | abc        |  |
|          2 | xxxx       |  |
|          3 | ababab     |  |
+------------+------------+--+
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? What data type is the `priority` column? If it's a string it will be sorted lexicographically so you'll have to cast it as an integer.

Comment: It's `INT`. So, should I change something ?

Comment: Can you give table structure for both tables?

Comment: not directly related to the question at hand, but it'd probably be a lot cleaner to use an `IN` clause as opposed to the long series of `or` statements at the end.  As it's written, it will work fine, but an `IN` clause would make it a little easier to read and understand what your intentions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
order by sp.'priority'
```

Assuming it is in the table.  If this doesn't work we need your schema.

**Edit**

```
SELECT `product_id`,
s.name AS Specification,
`value` 
FROM `specs-product` sp 
inner join `specifications` s on s.`specification_id` = sp.`specification_id`
WHERE `product_id`='4' 
AND
(s.`specification_id`='88' or 
s.`specification_id`='103' or 
s.`specification_id`='18' or 
s.`specification_id`='15' or 
s.`specification_id`='157' or 
s.`specification_id`='89' or 
s.`specification_id`='9' or 
s.`specification_id`='223' or 
s.`specification_id`='224' or 
s.`specification_id`='29' or 
s.`specification_id`='87' or 
s.`specification_id`='219' or 
s.`specification_id`='218' or 
s.`specification_id`='220')
order by s.priority
```

Comment: `priority` is the column in the table `specifications`

Comment: Error: `Column 'specification_id' in where clause is ambiguous `

Comment: Can we specify the Priority limit? Say not to include `0` ?

Comment: Yes you can. Please ask one question at a time.  If this solves your initial question, mark it as answered.  If it's not working, then post a screenshot of your query and the output.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark as accpeted and good luck!